# Laravel update hasMany relationship using saveMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As the title suggests, i'm trying to update a hasMany() relationship.  I have a `Contacts` and a `ContactsProperties` model in my application.

Contacts can have many properties associated with them.

My models are setup like so:

`Contacts` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contacts extends Model
{
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'contacts';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'contact_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'telephone', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
];

/**
 * Get properties associated with contact
 */
public function properties()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContactsProperties::class, 'contact_id');
}
}
```

`ContactsProperties` Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContactsProperties extends Model
{
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'contacts_properties';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'property_type', 'contact_id', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2', 'city', 'county', 'postcode'
];

/**
 * Get the contact that is assigned to the properties
 */
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contacts::class);
}
}
```

I can create new properties for a contact by doing:

```
$contact->properties()->createMany($request->address);
```

Which works perfectly.

My problem is when I want to update the properties, when editing the contact.  I have tried this:

```
$contact = Contacts::find($request->id);
        
        // Update properties
        $contact->properties()->saveMany($request->address);
```

Which gives the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in /var/www/MyApp/2016/public/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php on line 237

The value of $request->address is an array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [address_line_1] => test
        [address_line_2] => Lane
        [city] => Test
        [county] => test
        [postcode] => test
        [property_type] => site
    )

)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As error says it expects model instance, not an array. Try to create a `ContactsProperties` instance from that request input, then you able to save it, f.e.

```
$contactProperties = new ContactProperties($request->address);
$contact->properties()->saveMany($contactProperties);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this gives me the following error Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, boolean given, called in /var/www/MyApp/2016/public/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php on line 237

Comment: did you dump `$vcontactProperties` ? where do you call `save()` method? please share the whole class where you save contact properties.

Answer (score 0):

The `saveMany()` methods takes a collection of models as the parameter (see [the documentation](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_saveMany)). You cannot pass it an associative array. The error you received in from the `save()` method, which is called once for each model in the collection, and expects a `Model` as the parameter.

The `saveMany()` method will insert new rows for new models and update rows for existing models.

It seems that that you are saving one `ContactProperties` model at a time, in which case you could call the `save()` method directly, instead of `saveMany()`, but you need to pass it a `ContactProperties` model, not the associative array from the request.

```php
$contactProperties = new ContactProperties($request->address);
$contact->properties()->save($contactProperties);
```